# Color not changing using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the default "CSS class"to be black, and when using this select function for "selected" to have white text. I don't know where I'm going wrong

```
$(function() {
   $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('a.link').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       $(this).css('color', 'white');
       $(this).addClass('result-holder');
       $(this).css('color', 'black');


   });
});
```

Image demonstrating the problem:

[image]

[http://imgur.com/AquDa](https://imgur.com/AquDa)

Comment: I'd guess it's because you turn the link back to black at the end of the function?

Comment: Thanks Etienne. However, as I move down using onClick, the item above is "whited out" because there is no black. I have the problem where I want the default color (except for selected) to be black, and the selected item to be white because its on a blueish colored background. I hope I make some sort of sense (new to this!)

Comment: You are messing inline css with classes css. Not a good idea. stick with one of them.

Comment: Thanks gdron - Would you propose not having "CSS classes" and using jquery to set them?

Comment: `.addClass` and `removeClass` should be used instead of `.css` add to the classes definition 'color' property.

Comment: Your code could be improved if you used caching, local variables and method chaining. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Qb3Yr/1/

Comment: @MattCohen - What is the picture demonstrating?

Comment: @MattCohen - Does this do what you're asking? http://jsfiddle.net/Qb3Yr/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your existing code with an explanation of what it does any time any anchor tag with the class "link" is clicked:

```
$('a.link').removeClass('selected');   // remove 'selected' from all links
$(this).addClass('selected');          // add 'selected' to clicked link
$(this).css('color', 'white');         // turn clicked link 'white'
$(this).addClass('result-holder');     // add 'result-holder' to clicked link
$(this).css('color', 'black');         // turn clicked link 'black'
```

You are turning the clicked link white and then turning it back to black all in the same block of code so you'll never see it displayed as white.

I'm pretty sure what you really want to do is as follows:

```
$('a.link').removeClass('selected')    // remove 'selected' from all links
           .css('color', 'black');     // and make them black again

$(this).addClass('selected')           // add 'selected' to clicked link
       .css('color', 'white').         // and turn it 'white'
```

(Note if calling more than one function on a jQuery object you can "chain" them, like `$(this).addClass('selected').css('color','white');)`

I can't really tell what you want to do with the 'result-holder' class, because your current code adds it to the clicked link but doesn't remove it from anything. If you want to add it to the clicked link say `$(this).addClass('result-holder')` like you already do.

Note that you can simplify this by just adding `color:white;` to your 'selected' class definition, and setting `color:black;` in your default `a.link` styling:

```
a.link {
   color : black;
}    

a.selected {
   /* your existing style settings here, then: */
   color : white;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/6qURY/

Comment: I solved it with this. <script>
$(function() {
   $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('a.link').removeClass('selected');
           $('a.link').css('color', 'black');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       $(this).css('color', 'white');        
       
   });
});

</script>

Comment: @MattCohen - You don't need to use `$.css()` for this; put it in the classes, that's what they're for.

Comment: @MattCohen - The code you said you went with is what I said in my answer except that I had the functions chained together so that you only have to say `$(a.link)` once and `$(this)` once - which makes it both neater and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing it to black again...

```
  $(this).css('color', 'white');
   $(this).addClass('result-holder');
   $(this).css('color', 'black');  // <====
```

it's equals to:

```
var color = 'white';
color = 'black';
alert(color); //black...
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish. Thanks for the demo. But I think it's pretty obvious what's wrong in his code... =)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your comment is getting at; it was literally meant to show in practice what you were demonstrating in the answer. If you don't want it as a comment, I can remove it, but it wasn't really for you, per se.

Comment: @JaredFarrish. Thanks! no need for that. =)

Comment: Thanks Jared. Can you have a look at the image and see if you see a solution to this problem?